# Where sources committed to Git are stored in the server?

Tags: git

I created a shared Git repository in the server:

```
git init --bare repo_name.git
```

All works fine, I can clone the repository to the local folder and commit the files to the repository.

But I do not see commited files in my *repo_name.git* directory in the server, only config files:

- branches
- config
- description
- HEAD
- hooks
- info
- objects
- refs

So there my committed sources are stored in the server?

Comment: RT*M about what `--bare` does.

Answer (score 3):

In any git repo the committed files are in the objects folder, named after the sha1 hash. The files you normally work with are not the committed files, but a copy to for you to make modifications. Since no one is making modifications on the server, you don't need that copy, so you create a bare repo without the copy.

Comment: thank you :) I found the commit number in objects folder.